# Laravel: select entries created in the same day

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, datetime, eloquent

I have a Laravel model, `Users`. It utilizes standard Laravel's timestamp: `created_at` and `updated_at`.

I want to find Users created on the same date as the given user.

The problem is I can't directly compare database fields, as those fields also contain the time, like so: `2016-03-27 14:46:30`.

I want to do somehting like this:

```
User::where('created_at', $user->created_at);
```

But it doesn't seem to work that way.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Then I would had to get every record from database and create new Carbon Instance for each record, I'd prefer to not do so.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try to use `whereDate` condition instead :

```
$q->whereDate('created_at', '=', $your_date);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, works like a charm. I believe I already saw this method in documentation, but hadn't realized it's purpose at the moment.

Comment: The down side of this solution is that indexes cannot be used because `whereDate` uses a function.